# Android SDK is not working properly

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.3

I have updated android SDK. Now, when I am setting the path in Eclipse Helios-> Windows-> Preference -> android for this new SDK, I am getting error

"Failed to get the required ADT version number from the SDK"

So, I tried to check my ANDROID SDK. But when I click on sdk manager.exe file, one dialog box appears, which says

```
D:\ANDROI~1\SDKMAN~1.EXE
THE NTVDM CPU has encountered an illegal instruction.
CS:058c IP:012e OP:63 65 20 50 72
```

Can any one help me please.

Comment: What is the version of eclipse you are using?

Comment: Try updating the same with Eclipse: `Help > Check for Updates`. And restart Eclipse after the update (if at all update takes place!). Then see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: Well, if it won't even let you open sdk manager, then you could uninstall/reinstall the sdk.

Comment: Version Is Helios Service Release 2

Comment: I have checked for updates too. Nothing helped.